# Autoscrolling infinite effect in .linear type of iCarousel in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, icarousel

I need infinite autoscrolling effect in .linear type in iCarousel and i already achieve autoscrolling in .cylinder type but i can't achieve this effect in .linear type.

Here is my code of achieve autoscrolling in .cylinder type

```
carousel.type = .linear
```

carousel.autoscroll = -0.4;

```
carousel.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks **@salman** for an answer with the help of Salman's answer I got a solution for an infinite solution without jerking issue when carousel type is linear

Please follow the steps given below.

**1. Define timer for handle scrolling**

`_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 4, target: self, selector: #selector(self.handleTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

**2. Write the delegate method of the carousel and handle wrap type with the help of wrap we solve jerk issue.**

```
    func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        switch option {
        case .wrap:
            return 1
        default:
            return value
        }
    }
```

**3. Method to handle scrolling**

```
    func handleTimer() {
        var newIndex = self.carousel.currentItemIndex + 1

        if newIndex > self.carousel.numberOfItems {
            newIndex = 0
        }

        carousel.scrollToItem(at: newIndex, duration: 0.5)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this does not work `carousel.type = .linear` in the case of `linear` so you have to make an own timer for scrolling just like that:

```
self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(6, target: self, selector: #selector(self.handleTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func handleTimer(){

    if itemsScroll.count != 0{
        if itemsScroll.count-1 == index{
           index = 0           
        }
        else {
           index += 1
        }
    }
    let x = CGFloat(index)
    if index == 0 {
       carousel.scrollToOffset(x, duration: 0)
    }
    else {
       carousel.scrollToOffset(x, duration: 2)
    }
}
```

The `index` is used to get the current data for the carousel data source.

Comment: Thanks @salman for answer it, but in this after final item jerk happens when goes to first item.